# Oracle Client vs ODP.NET is ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

We've developed an ASP.net application using Oracle Client for database connection,

Our application is running on Windows Server 2003 server

Now we want to move to Windows Server 2008 server and change the driver to ODP.NET,

I have noticed using some loadtest, that with ODP.NET, the application consumes more memory than with Oracle Client, for a test with 230 users and Oracle client the average memory used is 793 MB

With ODP.NET, for the same loadtest configuration, the average memory used is 871 MB

My question is why with ODP.NET we consume more memory than with Oracle Client?

Some search on the Internet indicates that ODP.NET puts the schema information in the cache, can you confirm that?

Oracle version : 11.2.0

Comment: How is the performance when comparing them?

Comment: I have the same request response time, and % CPU Time when using Oracle Client or ODP.NET

Answer (score 0):

[Technical Comparison: ODP.NET Versus Microsoft OracleClient](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-154765.html)

> ...the schema information in the cache,

It is not listed but it does cache your statement.

> ...many of the classes in the
>   System.Data.OracleClient namespace are
>   marked as obsolete. Microsoft no
>   longer is going to keep working on
>   them in the future.

and from [this post](http://www.gbogea.com/2010/05/05/oracleclient-vs-odpnet-performance-benchmark), it says that microsoft won't maintaining the driver anymore.